# Compare change between 2 timepoints with two (paired) variables for paired subjects

Tags: r, regression, correlation, t-test, medicine

*This was a difficult question to search for, so my apologies if it has already been posted.*

Hi,

I have the following data in R:

I `data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
   SubjectID = c("726", "726", "729", "729", "768", "768", "781", "781", "782",
                 "782", "791", "791", "798", "798", "764", "764", "769", "769",
                 "787", "787", "789", "789", "797", "797", "799", "799", "727",
                 "727", "759", "759", "760", "760", "766", "766", "771", "771",
                 "772", "772", "728", "728", "730", "730", "763", "763", "765",
                 "765", "777", "777"),
   TimePoint = c("D11", "D22", "D11", "D22", "D11", "D22", "D11", "D22", "D11",
                 "D22", "D11", "D22", "D11", "D22", "D11", "D22", "D11", "D22",
                 "D11", "D22", "D11", "D22", "D11", "D22", "D11", "D22", "D11",
                 "D22", "D11", "D22", "D11", "D22", "D11", "D22", "D11", "D22",
                 "D11", "D22", "D11", "D22", "D11", "D22", "D11", "D22", "D11",
                 "D22", "D11", "D22"),
           A = c(9.69806226494383, 7.37716996381106, 9.20009812458429,
                 8.72320060153537, 9.7224043086594, 8.90760185945818,
                 9.85239455603795, 8.75035316831918, 10.4001285338843, 10.3983142889623,
                 9.02789906685704, 7.85986336471475, 7.86746969097554,
                 8.53536067395687, 9.92257117292426, 3.64652735285398, 9.59546267487877,
                 6.18101662995153, 10.9207464930092, 7.27966945010234,
                 9.83373141188921, 3.76156140672193, 9.92186855736, 6.76459919843807,
                 9.63566307109653, 3.72289366418138, 10.288282158214, 10.3645835550194,
                 9.81559965707614, 10.6841561324374, 10.2667129005731,
                 10.5223823858081, 9.2308823739852, 9.26240522731468, 10.2492015714547,
                 11.1356545961631, 9.74983525266318, 6.17167214447287,
                 9.47758844605777, 6.64807650960952, 9.61544346440473, 5.34366018904797,
                 9.74348227229929, 7.2470257661335, 9.44028607633272, 5.85464673394868,
                 9.52167205951673, 6.99178356304479),
           B = c(9.65846977752505, 8.6318346745598, 9.1570393050778,
                 7.53330620026698, 9.25582570944946, 6.38762719892321,
                 9.67730922647957, 8.77151839829561, 10.1463125636589, 7.63496197173443,
                 9.82555783663985, 7.94878379985945, 9.4353499246345,
                 9.55293410171811, 9.06891607914121, 4.90485588945599, 9.52299057033367,
                 5.41184176579826, 9.53950464335173, 6.63685481330296,
                 9.01843592877478, 5.16497554291081, 9.98450176864655, 5.74427669181849,
                 7.18545794534125, 2.79142347118977, 9.54013031212977,
                 10.0764946464362, 9.4107969197749, 9.85424719608698, 8.75364799762159,
                 10.8186122883268, 8.84256231481125, 6.29384998110262, 10.2702209765161,
                 10.3094950618958, 10.2911406932814, 9.6344075260481,
                 8.66730267436569, 4.64264082044521, 9.84799733137957, 7.21316000050277,
                 9.53668728820852, 6.08300469620964, 9.98631850043422,
                 6.5296255198579, 9.60009200705508, 7.50814032731335),
       Group = as.factor(c("9H10", "9H10", "9H10", "9H10", "9H10", "9H10",
                           "9H10", "9H10", "9H10", "9H10", "9H10", "9H10",
                           "9H10", "9H10", "COMBO", "COMBO", "COMBO", "COMBO",
                           "COMBO", "COMBO", "COMBO", "COMBO", "COMBO", "COMBO",
                           "COMBO", "COMBO", "CTRL", "CTRL", "CTRL", "CTRL", "CTRL",
                           "CTRL", "CTRL", "CTRL", "CTRL", "CTRL", "CTRL", "CTRL",
                           "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT",
                           "RT"))
)`

I can illustrate the data using the following code `ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x=B, y=A, group=SubjectID, color=Group)) +
      geom_line(size = 0.3) + 
      geom_point(aes(size=TimePoint)) +
      theme_bw(6) + 
      theme(legend.position = "right") +
      facet_grid(Statistic ~ Group, drop = T) + 
      scale_color_manual(values=c("black", "green3", "red", "blue"), guide=FALSE) +
      scale_size_manual(values=c(0.05, 0.7)) +
      xlab("TCR\u03b2-chain") +
      ylab("TCR\u03b1-chain")`

[image: Plot of data with four panels]

I should explain the data. `SubjectID` are individual mice in this case. A and B columns represent (kind of) an abundance value for two different chains of the same protein we are measuring the abundance of. `TimePoint` are day 11 and 22 (D11 and D22). Groups are four treatment groups (CTRL untreated, COMBO double treatment, and RT and 9H10 single treatment groups).

Now to the tricky part: I want to test whether i have a change in value between day 22 and 11 using both A and B data. For example, in RT and COMBO groups, it is clear the changes are similar between the mice. However, I want to test this.

I have tried calculating correlation coefficients which works to some degree, but it doesn't contain any information about direction of change; only slope. I would want to do a paired t-test somehow but without loosing any information that each protein has two measurements, but I am not sure how to proceed.